# Inner join causes multilplying of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Got such query:

```
   SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(PCH.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
,COALESCE(datepart(week,PS.SessionDate),0) as [Week]
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.ActionArchiveId = CA.CaseActionId
join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(CDV.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, datepart(week,PS.SessionDate)
UNION
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
,'0'
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(CDV.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName
order by
CDV.SetId
```

First part of query works as it should. In second part (after union all)

```
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
```

makes values inside

```
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
```

to be multiplied

I don't really have an idea how to pass it. Any ideas?

After removing rows connected with CaseActionHistory in 2nd and join itself the values are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone would have same problem anytime:

Solved with using subquery instead of inner join

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `Union` instead of `Union all`, because `UNION` retrieves only distinct values from both `Select`s

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

the values are multiplied but are probably different.

Union instead of a union all will just do a distinct, if there is different value, the "duplicates" will remain cause they are not fully identical.

and you should have a line

val, val, val, 1 as weeknumber
valdiff, valldiff, valldiff, null as weeknumber.

I don't really have an idea of what is wrong, could you show 3 lines of results and what you don't want or is wrong. 
At this moment as i understand your query, it should show sum by a difference of week and a global sum without week. So if datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate),0) is always equal to 0 yes you have 2 lines, one with 0 and the other one with null

instead of null use 0 and use a group by it could perhaps give you the solution you want.

Comment: Updated first post with current query. Since use of "datediff" wasn't exactly what client wanted. Anyway problem remains.